# Forcing new thread in Gmail

Tags: email, smtp, gmail

We send an automated email whenever someone signs up for our app.

The subject is always the same for every user.
Let's say the subject is 'Welcome'.

The problem is that whenever someone replies, it always end up in a single giant thread in gmail.

So the emails from various users are interleaved with each other, which makes it very difficult to manage.

What we want is a single thread per user (i.e per recipient email address)  so that we can keep the conversation with each person separate.

I'm aware that gmail has its own way of grouping messages into thread based on the subject line by default.

However, we noticed that some support tools (such as Zendesk) have somehow find a way to keep each email separate even though the same subject line is used. They seem to have a work around.
What I mean is that we have received multiple emails from the Zendesk email sender with the same subject and somehow they end up in multiple threads in our gmail.
They don't seem to use a uniquely generated email either. The from and reply-to address is simply support@domain.com

How do they do it?

We experimented with the 'Message-ID' and 'In-Reply-To' SMTP headers but were unsuccessful. 
Sending emails with different Message-ID still end up in the same thread.

See example of a Zendesk email received to my gmail address below:

[image]

Comment: With Zendesk, I just tested sending an outbound email with the same subject to the same user, and it was put into the same thread by the client's Gmail.  On the other hand, if I send the message to Zendesk from the user first, then reply with Zendesk, indeed there are two separate threads.  In your Zendesk example, did Zendesk send the message to you first and was it to the same user?

Comment: In my case I am receiving emails from Zendesk but I think the ticket already existed in Zendesk and I was included in the ticket.

Comment: So, someone else opened the ticket, and then it was sent to me via Zendesk, if that makes sense.

Comment: But Gmail is not aware of that obviously. So I'm thinking they must be using some SMTP magic I don't know about.

Comment: I do know that they also use the "Reference" header, perhaps that's something you could try as well?  If I'm not wrong, the Message IDs of all of the previous emails in the thread will be listed in the Reference header.

Comment: I just checked and there is no 'References' header in the first email of the thread (it makes sense since it is the first) and Gmail still created a new thread, so it cannot be based on the 'References' header.

Comment: I hadn't thought of this before, but if Zendesk is using their own server to set all of the headers, they may have more ability to make Gmail thread the messages.  Are all of your messages being sent from Gmail , or do you have a separate server which is sending the messages and then you're using Gmail client to review and respond to the messages?

Comment: We use sendgrid to send messages and we have the ability to set custom headers.

Comment: So two unique emails sent to two different users thru Sendgrid.  They both reply to the 'reply-to' header.  Is this value the same or unique for each mail?  Is the email address in 'reply-to' managed by Gmail, or by Sendgrid?  Btw, I'm not familiar with Sendgrid so I may ask some obvious questions.

As for Zendesk, there is a unique reply-to email address for each support ticket, which may help to maintain the threading  For example, the reply-to address in my latest ticket is support+id1292@d3v-hotelafrica.zendesk.com.  Perhaps this could be helpful to you?

Comment: As mentioned in question the 'Reply-to' is NOT unique. It is simply support@domain.com. The 'In-Reply-To' is unique, but we experimented setting this header to a unique value and could not force a new thread.

Comment: I'm confused Clement, do you mean that the emails you are sending do not have unique 'reply-to' address, or the Zendesk ones do not?  I ask because in my experience and after having checked a Zendesk email, they are in fact unique.  If you are able to set the 'Reply-To' Header, is there a reason that you cannot make it unique?  You mentioned that you experimented with setting the header, but didn't mention what you set it to.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't post in the comment, will add to the answer here.  Sample headers in an email I received from Zendesk.  Note that they use the support email address + the ID of the support ticket as the 'Reply-To' address.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I added a screenshot as well. As you can see 'Reply-To' is not unique but 'In-reply-to' is. I tried setting unique values to 'In-Reply-To' and 'Message-Id' and send myself an email, but this didn't create a new thread.

Comment: Thanks Clement, a bit strange that we received these two different styles.  I can investigate why there is a unique ID in one and not the other, but before doing so, may I know if it would be possible for you to set a unique ‘Reply-to’ for each email thread in the style I showed?  You mentioned experimenting with ‘In-Reply-To’ but not ‘Reply-To’

Comment: But the thing is I'm not using zendesk. I use gmail to handle support and I want users to reply to me, not some random address.

Comment: Gmail allows aliasing, so it seems you could make the reply to unique.  So do it in the same manner as Zendesk by making the ‘reply-to’ unique and handling in zendesk.  If you can set a unique alias for each case then it may force gmail to thread, just like zendesk is doing.  Or perhaps Im missing the reason why you couldn’t set a unique address/ ‘reply-to’ via sendgrid?   So you’d do something like mysupport+customer1@domain.com, mysupport+customer2@domain.com.  Still handled in gmail, same email address, but each one with unique alias.

Comment: oh right, I guess I could give that a try, although even if it works it would be better to get it to work like zendesk. thanks for your help so far I'll have to do more testing.

Comment: The other trick is that zendesk email servers are processing the responses so they can see the emails are related, then add the appropriate reference headers so gmail then knows they’re in the same response.  If sendgrid allowed you to modify the reference headers, or did so itself automatically, it may help with the threading in gmail.

Comment: Right, I'll have to experiment with the References header as well. I wished gmail was more transparent about how they do threading...

Comment: Yeah, it would be nice.  Unfortunately Gmails not my area of expertise, but rather Zendesk, so I can find out more about their mail if needed and hopefully it helps.  Let us know how it goes